# Как использовать определенный экземпляр класса если у меня их несколько?

Tags: java, объекты

Допустим я создал с помощью цикла в классе несколько экземпляров другого класса. И мне нужно переместить некоторое количество в одну `ArrayList`, а некоторое в другой.

Как мне это сделать, это же не переменные с разными названиями, и не массив где каждому значению соответствует индекс?

Comment: Может вы приведете несколько строк кода для примера того, о чем хотите спросить?

Comment: А что вам мешает те экземпляры поместить в массив и работать с ними через указатель? Или поместить их в словарь?

Comment: @gil9red ничего, было только интересно, есть ли другой какой-нибудь способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    private String name;
    
    Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    String say() {
        return "I'm " + name;
    }
}


java.util.List<String> names = java.util.Arrays.asList("Ivan", "Petya", "Anna");
java.util.List<Foo> namesList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
java.util.Map<String, Foo> nameByFoo = new java.util.HashMap<>();

for (String name : names) {
    Foo foo = new Foo(name);
        
    namesList.add(foo);
    nameByFoo.put(name, foo);
}

// По индексу
System.out.println(namesList.get(0).say()); // "I'm Ivan"

// По ключу
System.out.println(nameByFoo.get("Ivan").say()); // "I'm Ivan"
```

Comment: А еще вопрос - если у меня внутри класса, экземпляр которого мне нужен, есть переменные, то как узнать мне значение этой переменной? arraylist.get(1).variable - нельзя, хотя по идее arraylist.get - это я достаю объект, а object.variable - это переменная.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно. Эта переменная должна быть `public`, как, например, функция `say`

Comment: Да, вы правы. А что значит "Arrays.asList"?

Comment: (Arrays.asList)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)] этот метод принимает произвольный список параметров и из них создает объект список интерфейс `List`, скорее всего там ArrayList. Я посчитал что через этот метод проще всего получить список строк для их перебора в цикле

Comment: Странно, мой код не работает, хотя ваш работает. Проверил ваш код(предварительно обернув верхнюю часть в класс и метод). 
Теоретически, он такой же как мой.
...(класс1)...
public Passenger(int startingFloor, int destinationFloor, int passengerID) {
 ...
    }
    public static void abc() {

    }
...(класс2)...
for(int i = 0; i < passengersNumber; i++) {
            passengerContainer.add(new Passenger(startingFloor, destintationFloor, i));
            passengerContainer.get(0).abc; - не находит abc
        }

Comment: А так `passengerContainer.get(0).abc();`? Если не получится, создайте вопрос по этой проблеме и киньте, пожалуйста, сюда ссылку -- интересно посмотреть

Comment: 1)Да 
2)https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849468/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: @АнтонСорокин, увидел что вам уже помогли :)

Answer (score 1):

Переменные в цикле имеют локальную область видимости. Если вы создали объекты другого класса в цикле, то при последующей итерации они будут пересоздаваться заново. После создания объектов их надо сразу помещать в контейнер типа `ArrayList<>`. Это обобщенный тип и вы можете использовать тип параметра для создания коллекции объектов определенного типа. Или же типом параметра является суперкласс, то тогда в коллекцию можно добавлять этот класс и подклассы.

```
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (;;){
  SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
  SomeSubClass ssc = new SomeSubClass();
  list.add(sc);
  list.add(ssc);
  if (condition) break;
}

List<SomeClass> someClasses = list.stream()                
            .filter(o -> o instanceof SomeClass)     
            .collect(Collectors.toList());   

someClasses.forEach(System.out::println);

List<SomeSubClass> someSubClasses = list.stream()                
            .filter(o -> o instanceof SomeSubClass)     
            .collect(Collectors.toList());   

someSubClasses.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: А если 
Object object;
while(...) {
  object = new Object();
}

Comment: то тогда не обязательно указывать тип параметра, хотя можно указать тип `Object`.